# Integral algebra problems

Tags: integration

I guess the integral part is irrelevant but can anybody tell me how

∫(u+1)√u*du

is equivalent to

∫u$^\frac 32$ + u$^\frac 12$*du ?

Should it not be

∫u*du + u$^\frac 12$*du  ?

∫u$^\frac 32$ + u$^\frac 12$*du is given to me as a solution but it doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks!

Comment: It's just the distributive property. Note also that integration is linear so the two are equivalent.

Comment: Both of the expressions are awkward, because they lack brackets. Enclose things in brackets and both of them will start making sense

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(a+b)c = ac + bc$ and $\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Apply those to the given equation and the result follows.